# Why does this sequence generator not create a database table in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addition_type")
public class AdditionType {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "addition_type_id_seq", sequenceName = "addition_type_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "addition_type_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "sinhala_name")
    private String sinhalaName;

    @Column(name = "report_name")
    private String reportName;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CompanyInfo companyInfo;

    // there are not show getter and setter
}
```

When I use this class in Spring, two database tables were generated: the `AdditionType` table for the entity, and an `addition_type_id_seq` table corresponding to the sequence generator. The `AdditionType` table had the columns: id, name, code ..., and the other table had the `next value` of `id`.

When I use this class in Spring Boot it did not create two tables like that. Only the `AdditionType` table was created. Why is the `SequenceGenerator` not working in Spring Boot?

Comment: "AUTO" says leave it up to the JPA provider to decide what to do. Consequently there is no reason why it should "create a database table" for the generated values. Use "TABLE" if you want such a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MYSQL Dialect doesnt support sequences:

We can make use of Table Generator strategy to define the sequences :

```
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "addition_type_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, table = "ADDITION_TYPE_SEQUENCES",
                pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
                        valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER",
                pkColumnValue = "SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "addition_type_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
```

This will ensure creating two tables : ADDITION_TYPE_SEQUENCES and ADDITION_TYPE